# One IE process kills all IE processes

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, process

I'm developing a service in **VB.net**. The problem is if more than 1 IE windows are running, whenever i end a iexplorer process it doesn't close the corresponding IE window. i.e. if 4 windows are running i try to end 3 processes(That arrived after first process) one by one none of them closes but when i end that particular process(That arrived first) that is somehow holding all processes all Internet Explorers close down.

What i'm trying to do is i want commandline args of IE processes and i get args of first IE but after that i get  this:
 `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://ksnap.bpweb.com/webtop/drl/versionLabel/CURRENT"`

Thats what i want but when second IE process arrives i get this:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" SCODEF:424 CREDAT:79874"`

and for all next arriving IE processes i get args :i.e. **SCODEF:xxxx CREDAT:xxxx** (xxxx represent digits)

Comment: This makes no sense to me at all.  Can you try re-wording/re-explaining the problem?

Comment: -If i open 4 Internet explorers task manager shows 4 processes
-all processes are like attached to the first process 
-if i close one IE window,  process still stays there
-all processes stay as long as i keep even one explorer
thats why im unable to get commandline args of processes that arrive after the first process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be doing this by killing processes.  You should be use internet explorer automation.

In c#:

```
using SHDocVw;
using mshtml;

   private static IEnumerable<InternetExplorer> GetInternetExplorers()
   {
      ShellWindows shellWindows = new ShellWindowsClass();
      List<InternetExplorer> allExplorers = shellWindows.Cast<InternetExplorer>().ToList();
      IEnumerable<InternetExplorer> internetExplorers = allExplorers.Where( ie => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( ie.FullName ).ToLower() == "iexplore" );
      return internetExplorers;
   }
```

References:

```
MSHTML - Microsoft HTML Object Library
Interop.SHDocVw.dll - Microsoft Internet Controls
```

Look into this a bit more, you should be able to find and close open tabs.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this. i'll let you know asap